DESeq2 for GeoMx Data
I am currently experiencing difficulties to run the DESeq2 analysis for finding DEGs for my GeoMx Data.
The place I am stuck at is the constructing of the DESeqDataSet object.
packageVersion("DESeq2")
‘1.44.0’
R version 4.4.1
The dataset was normalised by RUV4.
The tutorials I am following are:
▾https://lashlock.github.io/compbio/R_presentation.html
▾https://master.bioconductor.org/packages/release/workflows/vignettes/rnaseqGene/inst/doc/rnaseqGene.html#the-deseqdataset-object-sample-information-and-the-design-formula
So far the top 2 lines successfully ran, but the last part - "DEseqDataSetFromMatrix" function is not working with the tidy = TRUE.

From the tutorial, it states that the tidy=TRUE argument tells DESeq2 to output the results table with rownames as a first #column called 'row.
Would it be okay to continue without the tidy = TRUE part?
Thank you in advance. It would be amazing if I could get through this and go on to the next step.

Code:
HNcountdata <- round(assays(HNspe_ruv)[["counts"]])
HNcoldata <- colData(HNspe_ruv)

HNdds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = HNcountdata, colData = HNcoldata, design=~biology, tidy = TRUE) 

Error
Error in .rowNamesDF<-(x, value = value) :
duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
Dataset:
colData(HNspe_ruv)
DataFrame with 3 rows and 36 columns
SlideName              ScanLabel    ROILabel        SegmentLabel

\<character\>        \<character\> \<character\>  \<character\>

Origin Instrument ID   QCFlags AOISurfaceArea AOINucleiCount ROICoordinateX

\<character\>         \<logical\>\<numeric\>    \<numeric\>    \<numeric\>

ROICoordinateY  RawReads AlignedReads DeduplicatedReads TrimmedReads StitchedReads

\<numeric\>   \<numeric\> \<numeric\>    \<numeric\>     \<numeric\>    \<numeric\>

SequencingSaturation      SequencingSetID    UMIQ30    RTSQ30

\<numeric\>               \<character\>    \<numeric\> \<numeric\>

ROIID         SegmentID  ScanWidth ScanHeight ScanOffsetX

\<character\>  \<character\> \<numeric\>  \<numeric\>   \<numeric\>

ScanOffsetY Disease_status     Regions   sample_id  lib_size countOfLowEprGene

\<numeric\> \<character\> \<character\> \<character\>\<numeric\> \<numeric\>

percentOfLowEprGene     biology     ruv_W1     ruv_W2

\<numeric\>          \<character\> \<numeric\>  \<numeric\>

*I have intentionally deleted the content inside the table, which I hope will not be a problem to understand the structure of my dataset.

If I delete the tidy = TRUE,
it does run, but it comes up like this.
converting counts to integer mode
Warning: some variables in design formula are characters, converting to factors  Note: levels of factors in the design contain characters other than
letters, numbers, '' and '.'. It is recommended (but not required) to use
only letters, numbers, and delimiters '' or '.', as these are safe characters
for column names in R. [This is a message, not a warning or an error]

Why not, if you trust the results otherwise? This only impacts a specific formatting style that some prefer. The tidy approach is overrated anyway. BTW, if you aren't dependent on DESeq2, I would consider limma instead.

Thank you for the reply. I have tried searching why limma would be more suitable for the GeoMx dataset, but other than the fact that they give a more strict list of DEG, I could not find the reason. Why do you suggest the latter?

It's more precise and also more efficient. See e.g. there.
